# How do I set a column width to be the whole table width (fixed) minus another column (auto adjusted for text)?

Tags: css

I'm setting the css property of a table with two columns. The table width is 100% of its parent (parent at fixed width). The first column is auto-fitted by the content width (no wrap). The second column width should be table width minus first column width, and the overflow text should be truncated.

Currently, I only need it to work on Chrome.

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
}

.td-value {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr class="tr">
    <td class="td-key ">Key</td>
    <td class="td-value ">A long value</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: there is no possibilities here, or you reset the table-layout to fixed and  overflow can happen so text-overflow , but each column will be the same width unless you set to each a .. fixed width. Flex or grid could do that better (flx:x; or 1fr ) , but how is your table in real ?  Would the flex or grid option be efficient here to reset display properties of your table ?

Comment: here is an example from my previous comment https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/KOdYvP , please , clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it giving the value column `width: 100%` and wrapping the content in a flex container, which constrains the size of the child.

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid #888;
}

.td-key {
  width: auto;
}

.td-value {
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.cell-content {
  width: 0;
  flex: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr class="tr">
    <td class="td-key">Key</td>
    <td class="td-value">
      <div class='flex-wrapper'>
        <div class='cell-content'>
        A very very very very 
        very very very very very 
        very very very very very 
        very very very very very 
        very very very very very 
        very very very very very 
        long value
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```